# How to stick UIView to the right side of it's superview programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am desperately trying to stick one of my UILabels to the right edge of it's superview while the label's width is variable (it's a time so the thing is getting bigger and should be expanding to the left, this is done using sizeToFit inside of the label when text is set).

So far I have tried loads of things but closest I got with:

```
_elapsedTimeRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_elapsedTimeView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-150];
```

While the label is initially set to 150px width. But when I modify the constant, it all goes to hell.

```
_elapsedTimeRightConstraint.constant = (_elapsedTimeView.frame.size.width * -1);
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

So my question is, how do I align trailing edges of a view and it's superview (so it sticks to the right) when the width of the subview is constantly changing. I have been using `FLKAutoLayout` elsewhere in the project so if this can be done this framework easily than great, but basic autolayout solution would be amazing too!!!

Comment: Are you creating the label programmatically? If so, make sure you have set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`  Secondly you should use `NSLayoutConstraintTrailing` rather than `NSLayoutConstraintRight` (and leading rather than left) as this makes your layout work in right-left languages. You shouldn't have -150 for the constant you just want 0 and you don't need to modify the constraint because labels automatically adjust their intrinsic size as the content changes. Finally, unless you are doing something super tricky use Interface Builder. It is so much easier than coding it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure that `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `NO`, if you are creating the label programmatically.

The first constraint you need is "label.trailing = superview.trailing".

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label 
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:superview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                            multiplier:1.f
                              constant:0.f]
```

This will pin the right edge (on left-to-right languages) of the label on the right edge of the superview.

You will now need a constraint for the `Y` position.

In my test, I have vertically centred the label with the following constraint:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label 
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:superview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                            multiplier:1.f
                              constant:0.f]
```

Now comes the trick!

Every time you change the text on the label, you need to recalculate the frames with AutoLayout.

```
[superview setNeedsLayout];
[superview layoutIfNeeded];
```

AutoLayout will:

1) Ask the label of its new size (based on its text).

2) Adjust the size of the label.

3) Pin the trailing edge of the label to the trailing edge of the superview.

---

**Further research**

The issue with UILabel is that when you're using AutoLayout and you set text, its `intrinsicContentSize` changes, but it doesn't trigger a layout update.

A way to enforce this without subclassing UILabel is to use Objective-C runtime.

```
@interface UILabel (AutoLayout)

- (void)swz_setText:(NSString*)text;

@end

@implementation UILabel (AutoLayout)

+ (void)load
{
  NSLog(@"Swizzling [UILabel setFont:]...");

  Method oldMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(setText:));
  Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swz_setText:));

  method_exchangeImplementations(oldMethod, newMethod);
}

- (void)swz_setText:(NSString*)text
{
   if (![text isEqualToString:self.text]) {
       [self setNeedsLayout];
   }
   [self swz_setText:text]; //This now points to "setText:" - not a mistake!
}

@end
```

In this category, I'm "enhancing" `setText:` implementation by calling `setNeedsLayout` if the text changes.

Now you just need to invoke `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview to recalculate/realign the label frame.

---

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-u1U7yqXGelQnBYUUlHRWpPMzA/view?usp=sharing) for the playground (Swift 2.0 - Xcode 7) where I've tested my code.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hello here are some points to achieve what you want:

- Set **NSLayoutConstraintTrailing** constant **equal to 0** and the leading constraint **NSLayoutAttributeLeading** set it as **greater than or equal** the value you want.
- Use NSLayoutConstraintTrailing and NSLayoutAttributeLeading instead of right and left to handle other languages
  I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourLabel sizeToFit];    
CGRect frame = yourLabel.frame;
frame.x = parentView.frame.size.width - yourLabel.frame.size.width;
yourLabel.frame = frame;
```

It completely ignores the "best practice" of using the autolayout features, but if you just can't stand it anymore....that should work. ;-)